# Domain-specific C++ iterator methods

Tags: c++, iterator

Are there any reasons not to include non-standard methods in an iterator in addition to the normal methods required by the iterator concept?  The additional methods would be specific to the kind of items produced by the iterator.

---

### Concrete example

To make my question more concrete, I am interating over menu items in a GUI menu.  Internally the iterator accesses the menu by index. When dereferenced, it queries the menu for the item, at that index, creates an immutable object representating the properties returned by the menu and caches it in a member variable before returning a reference to it.

#### Unsafe solution

An alternative was to make the representation mutable and make it write property updates back to the underlying menu.  It would look something like this:

```
menu m = some_menu();
menu_iterator pos = m.begin() + 3;

menu_item i = *pos;
...
i.caption("foo");
i.disable();
```

This would mean each `menu_item` representation would have to store its position and a handle to the menu --- no big deal --- unless the menu has had an item inserted/removed since the item representation was created.  In that case, all sorts of hell might break loose as properties are changed for a completely different item.

#### Better solution?

So my idea was to add extra methods that change the properties to the *iterator* rather than the values it returns.  That way, the user is always aware that what is being updated is the item currently pointed to and the usual iterator semantics of insertions invalidating it apply (it wouldn't really invalidate it, it would just point to a different item).

```
menu m = some_menu();
menu_iterator pos = m.begin()+3;
...
pos.caption("foo");
pos.disable();
```

What do you think?

Comment: You kind of lost me in there... Would your iterator adhere to any of the standard iterator semantics or not?

Comment: this sounds a bit like premature optimization

Comment: @K-ballo Sorry, yes, the normal iterator semantics would be left unchanged.  Edited to clarify

Comment: @thehouse: As long as your iterator adheres and fulfills the semantic of one of the known iterator categories, you can add whatever extra methods/functionality you want.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf this isn't a matter of optimisation but safety.  If I return the caller an object they can quite resonably expect that mutating it will always mutate the conceptual 'method item object' they though they fetched. But, if the menu is extended or truncated, it will not.

Comment: @K-ballo I know I *can* but *should* I?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

- If you don't *need* to be able to mutate menu items via the iterator, just make `menu_item` immutable - problem solved.
- If you need to be able to mutate menu items via the iterator:

  - If you have that type of control over the underlying menu implementation, make `menu_item` point to the **actual** menu object that does not get invalidated when a new menu item gets added. You might even have the iterator return (by reference, of course) the actual menu object when dereferenced and do away with the `menu_item` wrapper altogether.
  - If you don't have that type of control, then `menu_item` is really a proxy to a menu item rather than a menu item itself. Call it `menu_item_proxy`, and document that it has proxy behaviour, and that proxies get invalidated when iterators get invalidated. Users can still call the methods "on the iterator" using the syntax `pos->caption("foo")`.

I would not put methods like `caption()` inside the iterator itself. (How would one use them with, say, `for_each`?)

Comment: There is no actualy underlying menu item object, just a menu handle and an integer.  I don't really want the callers to be aware of the way the underlying menu.  Calling the item a proxy seems to leak the fact this is just a wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

it's nothing wrong in adding methods to an iterator. iterator is just a special case of visitor. visitor is supposed to do all required action while he visits some object. feel free to add any method your business needs

Comment: Iterator is a special case of visitor? are you sure? in what way?

Comment: no, i'm not sure, i haven't read it anywhere. but as far as i know visitor is an object which goes through every element of some bigger structure and act if necessary. your situation is similar. similar is also e.g. patternMatcher - it goes through a string until it matches and then you can call a lot of methods on it (get matching groups, get position etc). if it helps you, just change name from iterator to visitor, menuChanger or whatever. if it seems to fit your needs and no one is giving good arguments against - just try it